# AttributeError: 'TransposedFont' object has no attribute 'getbbox'

Tags: python, databricks

I am getting this error on my databricks notebook for a word cloud.

I have looked into previous questions with the same title and got led to here: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/729#issuecomment-1567560863

I upgraded my pips (used subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'wordcloud'])) but everything remained the same. I also reinstalled wordcloud on my cluster.

Any other solutions?